# Adding SDK Activity in Qt for Android

Tags: java, android, qt, android-activity, qt5

Is there any way that we can add separate SDK (Java) Activity to the make process in Qt 5.2 for Android?

I have Qt application that I've compiled for Android and I want to start my own SDK Activity from it, and I was wondering if I can include that activity in the current application.

Answer (score 1):

Through JNI you can do that. Although it is probably not the only way. You can use the Qt Android Extra module. The example is really simple: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html.

Have a look in particular to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtandroid.html#startActivity.